# ¿Cómo puedo buscar escalas de un vuelo en txt?

Tags: java

Tengo un proyecto y tengo que buscar en archivo txt divido por comas. Es importante considerar que un viaje podría no ser precisamente directo, cabe la posibilidad que un viaje pueda contener escalas. Por ejemplo: Viajar de Costa Rica a Argentina podría no tener un vuelo directo, pero sí se podría tomar uno de Costa Rica a Colombia y otro de Colombia a Argentina. No se cómo solucionarlo.

```
public void tablaPasajero(JTable tb, File archivo,String aerosalida,String aerollegada){
        boolean existe = false;
        String []titulos = {"ID  Aerolinea",
            "Precio vuelo", "Fecha y hora salida",
            "Aeropuerto salida", "Fecha y hora llegada", "Aeropuerto llegada"};
         DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel(null,titulos);
        String datos= "";

        try {
            BufferedReader archi = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(archivo));
            
            
            while ((datos = archi.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] palabra = datos.split(",");
                if (palabra[5].equals(aerosalida) && palabra[8].equals(aerollegada)){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hay un vuelo directo para su viaje");
                        String fila[] = {palabra[1], "$" + palabra[2],
                            palabra[3] + palabra[4], palabra[5], palabra[6] + palabra[7],
                             palabra[8]};
                        existe = true;
                        modelo.addRow(fila);

            }else if(palabra[5].equals(aerosalida)   || palabra[8].equals(aerosalida)){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No un vuelo directo para su viaje " + "\n"
                            + "Hay escalas disponibles!!");
                        String fila[] = {palabra[1], "$" + palabra[2],
                            palabra[3] + palabra[4], palabra[5], palabra[6] + palabra[7],
                             palabra[8]};
                        existe = true;
                        modelo.addRow(fila);

                }
                
                
            }
            if (!existe) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No HAY NINGUN VUELO EN ESAS FECHAS");
                }
            
            
           tb.setModel(modelo);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR " + e);
        }
                
        
    }
```

Comment: como es ese "archivo txt separado por comas"? suena a CSV... me resulta extraño que no haya una libreria para tratar archivos csv en java...

Comment: no es un archivo txt, lo que necesito es el buscador de escala que no se como hacer

Comment: agrega cual es la estructura del archivo, un ejemplo

Comment: Este es mi txt  vu1,QA,2000,01/07/2020,11:11,Internacional de Galeão,02/07/2020,20:00,Internacional de El Salvador,455,208130717,208920345,408910651,208930445,109820345